# Windows server 2008 Connected but not responding

Tags: windows-server-2008

I  have a server here that was running normal! Now he does not want to access any shared folders, nor as a system administrator, even if I create the folder, he does not access. 
OBS: I checked the services, I checked the connection and everything is ok. Note: Ping test and Nslookup is all OK, the problem is when accessing shared folders from the server.
OBS2: I type: \ server
It opens the folders, but I can not access them.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the server?

Comment: Yes, but it did not work.

Comment: Have you by chance modified the permissions set to that partition? If you have a restrictive policy set on the drive, it will apply to all subfolders.

Comment: `Now he does not want to access any shared folders` - How about giving us specific details about the problem? What exactly happens when you try to access shared folders from this server? What messages do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you can mount and open shared folders but you can't see any files, it's certainly permissions problems.
Did you do modifcations on that ?

Comment: Agreed, sounds like the network doesn't trust your PC. Try to restore all permissions, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual error you are getting? Without that I can only give you generic help:
Check the Firewall.
Check IP Security policies.
Check the permission on the folders themselves.